# Cannot set property 'login' of undefined after add a new page?

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I'm running the app using ripple in visual studio. The JS developer tools shows the following error after adding a new page. Which line caused the error?

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 TypeError: Cannot set property 'login' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:4400/js/controllers.js:10:18)
    at invoke (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17770:27)
    at http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22326:28
    at Object.self.appendViewElement (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56883:24)
    at Object.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54995:41)
    at Object.init (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:54915:20)
    at Object.self.render (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56743:14)
    at Object.self.register (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56701:10)
    at updateView (http://localhost:4400/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62357:23) <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="android">
```

I did the following steps to add the page.

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['client', function (client, $scope, $state) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        client.login("facebook").then(function succes(data){
            console.log('logged in succesfully..')
            $state.go('menu.events');
        }, function(error){
            console.log('login failed.');
            //login failed.
        });
    }
}])
```

**routers.js**

```
  .state('menu.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        'side-menu21': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
    }
  })
```

**service.js**

```
.factory('client', [function () {
    var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/");
    return client;
}])
;
```

The file **login.html** is added.

```
<ion-view view-title="Sign in">
    <ion-content>
        <a class="item button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="login()">
            Sign In With Facebook
        </a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also added meta `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` and the reference in index.html: `<script src="js/azure-mobile-apps-client.min.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller definition you have written

`.controller('LoginCtrl', ['client', function (client, $scope, $state) {...})`

I think this should be as

`.controller('LoginCtrl', ['client', '$scope', '$state', function (client, $scope, $state)  {...})`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your `client` is not defined.  It's likely (if you can use developer tools) that you are trying to initialize it too early in the page lifecycle.  You cannot initialize the client until after the page onReady event has fired.

I'm not an ionic expert, but I believe `$ionicPlatform.ready()` is the thing you need to be looking at.